# How to correlated the xl/comments.xml to the sheet it corresponds to when unzip xlsx file?

Tags: xml, excel

I am unable to find any information that relates the xl/comments[i].xml file to the sheet it corresponds to. I also did not find any information for the same in xl/worksheets/sheet[i].xml. This issue arises because the comments[i].xml file are not numbered according to their sheets or any such information, they are just sequenced from 1 to any number.
It would be great if someone could help me out here.